# Unlayer EmailEditor import into React breaks application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to include Unlayer in my React Application following: https://github.com/unlayer/react-email-editor. I am using Webpack for this.

However as soon as I import EmailEditor into one of my modules:

```
import React from 'react';
import EmailEditor from 'react-email-editor';
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

my env:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-email-editor": "^0.9.0",
    "react-load-script": "0.0.6",
    "styled-components": "^4.1.2"
  }
```

Any idea what could be causing this bad import/export ?

Comment: Seems to be working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9e8fso Can you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of `styled-component` breaks for React version 16.0.0 as it depends on the new context API. New context API was introduced in react `v16.3.0`.

[image]

To fix the issue you can try one of the following.

1. Use any react version >= 16.3.0.
2. Use an older version of `styled-component` which does not require the new react context API. The new context API was introduced in styled-component [v4.0.0](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes)

See the broken version which uses react `v16.0.0`. https://codesandbox.io/s/9l25580ppy

See the working version which uses the latest react version `v16.6.3`
https://codesandbox.io/s/6lrv8zoj6r

See the working version which uses the older version of styled-components `v3.4.10`
https://codesandbox.io/s/xvo2658j7w

Comment: Glad it helped! :) You can also use the older version of styled-components as I have updated in the answer. Whatever works for you. :)